# объектная структура при передаче форм

Tags: php

есть ли смысл `ajax`ом передавать данные формы и создавать класс со своими методами в файле обработчике, либо же такой подход считается не правильным, и экземпляры нужно создавать в файлах не зависящих от `ajax` + встречный вопрос, можно ли без `<form>` загружать картинки использую тот же `ajax` со своим обработчиком

Comment: На счёт загрузки файла через ajax, в чём проблема, на стороне клиента как это сделать или что?

Comment: ну если сейчас я отправляю файлы на сервер через форму через атрибут `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, то можно ли убрать тэг формы и загружать файлы уже при вызове ajax

Comment: Вот тут описано как через ajax на JS передать файл, если я правильно вас понял. 
https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-onprogress

Comment: я бы хотел по клику на кнопку, на которую будет установлено событие вызова ф-и ajax, обращаться к php файлу с обработчиком загрузки. Вот такой вариант возможен? js в данном случае файлы не загружает

Comment: Не очень понимаю что именно вы хотите, так и получится, когда форма отправляется, js её блокирует, забирает её данные и передаёт через ajax (именно JS передаёт), посмотрите пример лучше.

Comment: я хотел сделать без формы , в примере же загрузку делает js